# Replacement using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following XML tag

```
<fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklightconsole/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
```

and after replacing it with 'sed' it should look like below

```
<fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/app/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
```

I should replace the word 'worklightconsole' with 'app'

I tried the following 'sed command' and few other options but I was unsuccessful and at the same time it did not throw any error

```
sed -E 's|(resource.dir/)[^/]worklightconsole(/lib")|\1app\2|'
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: If you want to replace `worklightconsole` with `app`, why not simply `sed 's|worklightconsole|app|g'`? What I'm missing?

Comment: @Maroun The word 'worklightconsole' exists (or) scattered all over the file.  I want to replace this particular instance

Comment: Does a slightly different regex strategy help? I don't have a shell handy right now to try with sed.. https://regex101.com/r/pT7aQ8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple issues with your pattern, mainly the way you have the capture groups defined perhaps, and in particular group 1:

```
sed 's|\(resource.dir}/\)worklightconsole\(/lib"\)|\1app\2|g
```

I believe you'll want to escape the `()` parentheses in the capture groups (at least that's what I typically need to do). And your first capture group was missing the `}` found in the original string. The last issue was that you've got `[^/]` which you might have backwards with the `/` in the first capture group — it's unclear, although I eliminated it from your pattern and it worked.

**Result**:

```
<fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/app/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
```

EDIT: Using the `-E` option avoids the need to escape the parentheses `()`:

```
sed -E 's|(resource.dir}/)worklightconsole(/lib")|\1app\2|g
```

Comment: Thanks for helping and explaining and in addition to your solution the following also works 'sed -E 's|(resource.dir}/)worklightconsole(/lib")|\1app\2|g' ie without escaping round paranthesis

Comment: Yep, glad to help - I think using `-E` option was a good thought too... it's cleaner :)